# is there a way to display audio waves bigger?

Tags: audio

is there a way to make the waves of my audio bigger? at the moment they are almost not visible.

[image]

At the moment it looks like this. When i render the animation the sound is good. but its difficult to work with these small waveforms.

Answer (score 2):

Select the audio strip and raise its Volume in the properties panel.

Some red vertical lines will indicate clipping if raised too high.

[image]

Comment: but then, when i render it will the sound be louder. my problem is that i have two soundstrips which have a different volume and i want to adjust them. so if i turn on the volume, then they are still not correct. 
is there an easy way to adjust the two sounds that they have the same volume?

Comment: Create a copy, raise the volume, then mute it during rendering.

Comment: @PaulHäni In the question you said it's difficult to work with these small waveforms... what kind of work? If it's just for positioning and maybe cutting and bigger waveforms make it easier to locate certain parts - then why render with the louder sound? Just set it back to normal volume when you finished editing. And for more complex audio editing I'd say: Blender isn't the best choice for editing audio tracks anyway and you should do it in a different software.

Comment: Highly recommend DaVinci Resolve for audio - free version is great

Comment: thanks for the answers, the work that i want to do is to adjust the  sounds of two different soundstrips, but i think you are right, i will use another audioprogram to make this.